# rails generate controller fails with "Ignoring binding_of_caller-0.7.2 because its extensions are not built."

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I run `rails generate controller welcome index` in my newly created rails app, I get the following answer

```
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring json-1.8.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine json --version 1.8.2
Ignoring binding_of_caller-0.7.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine binding_of_caller --version 0.7.2
Warning: Running `gem pristine --all` to regenerate your installed gemspecs (and deleting then reinstalling your bundle if you use bundle --path) will improve the startup performance of Spring.
Ignoring binding_of_caller-0.7.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine binding_of_caller --version 0.7.2
```

But no controller file is generated. 
Running `gem pristine --all` gives the following result:

```
Restoring gems to pristine condition...
Skipped bigdecimal-1.2.6, it is a default gem
Restored bundler-1.11.2
Restored bundler-1.10.6
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Restored curb-0.9.1
Skipped io-console-0.4.3, it is a default gem
Skipped json-1.8.1, it is a default gem
Restored minitest-5.4.3
Restored power_assert-0.2.2
Skipped psych-2.0.8, it is a default gem
Skipped rake-10.4.2, it is a default gem
Skipped rdoc-4.2.0, it is a default gem
Restored test-unit-3.0.8
```

Before running the generator, I had simply done

```
$ rails new testapp
$ cd testapp
```

My ruby version is `ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-darwin15]`, my rails version is `Rails 4.2.1`, I'm using rbenv.

I guess this is hardly reproductible ... but I haven't been able to find any post to help me with this. I'm not new to Ruby on Rails, but I haven't used it for a while.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it solved my problem, but switching from rbenv to RVM did it.

Before that, I started having the following error when running `rails server` :

```
/Users/aymericbouzy/Sites/jobwards/vendor/bundle/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json/ext.rb:13:in `require': incompatible library version - /Users/aymericbouzy/Sites/jobwards/vendor/bundle/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json/ext/parser.bundle (fatal)
from /Users/aymericbouzy/Sites/jobwards/vendor/bundle/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json/ext.rb:13:in `<module:Ext>'
from /Users/aymericbouzy/Sites/jobwards/vendor/bundle/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json/ext.rb:12:in `<module:JSON>'
from /Users/aymericbouzy/Sites/jobwards/vendor/bundle/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json/ext.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/aymericbouzy/Sites/jobwards/vendor/bundle/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json.rb:58:in `require'
from /Users/aymericbouzy/Sites/jobwards/vendor/bundle/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json.rb:58:in `<module:JSON>'
from /Users/aymericbouzy/Sites/jobwards/vendor/bundle/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json.rb:54:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/aymericbouzy/Sites/jobwards/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:2:in `require'
from /Users/aymericbouzy/Sites/jobwards/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/aymericbouzy/Sites/jobwards/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/object.rb:12:in `require'
from /Users/aymericbouzy/Sites/jobwards/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/object.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/aymericbouzy/Sites/jobwards/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/configuration.rb:2:in `require'
from /Users/aymericbouzy/Sites/jobwards/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/configuration.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/aymericbouzy/Sites/jobwards/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:2:in `require'
from /Users/aymericbouzy/Sites/jobwards/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/aymericbouzy/Sites/jobwards/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:1:in `require'
from /Users/aymericbouzy/Sites/jobwards/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/aymericbouzy/Sites/jobwards/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:6:in `require'
from /Users/aymericbouzy/Sites/jobwards/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/aymericbouzy/Sites/jobwards/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails.rb:11:in `require'
from /Users/aymericbouzy/Sites/jobwards/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/aymericbouzy/Sites/jobwards/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:4:in `require'
from /Users/aymericbouzy/Sites/jobwards/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/aymericbouzy/Sites/jobwards/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:123:in `require'
from /Users/aymericbouzy/Sites/jobwards/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:123:in `require_command!'
from /Users/aymericbouzy/Sites/jobwards/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:73:in `server'
from /Users/aymericbouzy/Sites/jobwards/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
from /Users/aymericbouzy/Sites/jobwards/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:9:in `require'
from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
```

which led me to other forums, and ultimately I decided to try RVM instead.